# How to find the local port of a socket in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, udp, port

I am creating a UDP socket using:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
```

When I use socket_getsockname to get the socket name:

```
   /**
    * Get Source port (Refactored to allow unit testing)
    *
    * @return string
    */
    private static function getSourcePort($sock)
    {
        $addr = null;
        $port = null;
        socket_getsockname($sock, $addr, $port);
        return $port;
    }
```

***The port returned is always 0 and the addr is 0.0.0.0***

How to get the bound port properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sockets, PHP, local port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640660/sockets-php-local-port)

Comment: Here the port returned is always 0 and the addr is 0.0.0.0

Comment: Well yes, you are creating the socket but you're not connecting it: `socket_connect($sock, $server_ip_here, $port_here)`; After that it should return the correct ip and port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding the socket after creation fixed the issue:

```
if (socket_bind($sock, $sourceIp) === false)
{
    $failReason = "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
}

// get the source port
$sourcePort = 0;
if (socket_getsockname($sock, $sourceIp, $sourcePort) === false)
{
    $failReason = "socket_getsockname() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
}
```